# Change the color of the EditText in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, text, colors

Change the color of the EditText in Android

I was trying to change the color of what the user writes inside an EditText (In Android)

I wanted to change it to white so i was wondering if i should do so in the XML ?
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: use android:textColor="#colorcode"

Comment: Use edittext.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

Comment: Answer to be validated in 4 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your EditText property.

```
android:textColor="#ffffff"
```

Ex:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:ems="10" >
```